# Unity Android. Failed to build with il2cpp. Mono works fine

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, il2cpp

I'm working on a game in Unity to release to the play store. Whenever I try to build the project, with mono as scripting backend works totally fine, but with il2cpp (to build in 64-bit) it gives some errors:

1:

```
Exception: Failed running C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.32f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build/deploy/netcoreapp3.1/UnityLinker.exe 
@"C:/Users/hide_path/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed/response.rsp"

stdout:
Fatal error in Unity CIL Linker
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Unity\Projects\Flappy Bird'.
File name: 'C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Unity\Projects\Flappy Bird'
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument.LoadFromReader(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space)
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(String uri, XmlSpace space)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.ParseArguments(UnityPipeline p, UnityLinkContext context, ArrayList custom_steps, Boolean usingCustomLogger, I18nAssemblies& assemblies)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.UnityRun(ILogger customLogger)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriverWithoutErrorHandling(ILogger customLogger)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriver()
stderr:

UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at <294703faec74477f8b275446429fba82>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunNetCoreProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at <294703faec74477f8b275446429fba82>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.RunAssemblyLinker (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] args, System.String& out, System.String& err, System.String linkerPath, System.String workingDirectory) (at <294703faec74477f8b275446429fba82>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.StripAssembliesTo (System.String outputFolder, System.String& output, System.String& error, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] linkXmlFiles, UnityEditorInternal.UnityLinkerRunInformation runInformation) (at <294703faec74477f8b275446429fba82>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.RunAssemblyStripper (UnityEditorInternal.UnityLinkerRunInformation runInformation) (at <294703faec74477f8b275446429fba82>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.StripAssemblies (System.String managedAssemblyFolderPath, UnityEditorInternal.BaseUnityLinkerPlatformProvider unityLinkerPlatformProvider, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider il2cppPlatformProvider, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry rcr, UnityEditor.ManagedStrippingLevel managedStrippingLevel) (at <294703faec74477f8b275446429fba82>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at <294703faec74477f8b275446429fba82>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at <294703faec74477f8b275446429fba82>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.RunIl2Cpp.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <a40de2f63ada42c98008dd43cde35512>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <a40de2f63ada42c98008dd43cde35512>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <a40de2f63ada42c98008dd43cde35512>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <a40de2f63ada42c98008dd43cde35512>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <294703faec74477f8b275446429fba82>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

2:

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 16 seconds (15590 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

3:

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer
(UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ca] in :0
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods
(System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in :0
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Try not having a space in the folder structure

Comment: @BugFinder It wasn't the space; it was a comma in the folder structure that il2cpp doesn't read and stop the name before that, mb Thank you

Comment: Any thing like that will mess it up.  But the details provided didn’t have a comma

Comment: @BugFinder Yeah because Unity with il2cpp stop reading at the comma, so it searches the file in a wrong path and gives you an error with that path